# CL/cl.h not found in windows intel opencl sdk?

Tags: opencl

I have installed intel opencl sdk in windows 8. All the files are located as they have to according to user guide but whenever I am trying to compile any code it is showing error that Cl/cl.h not found. Also, the user manual says that application needs to be linked to the libraries , but that option is nowhere to be found in the IDE.

This is the error I am getting at console
Setting target instruction set architecture to: Default (Advanced Vector Extension (AVX))
OpenCL Intel CPU device was found!
Device name:        Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Device version: OpenCL 1.2 (Build 82248)
Device vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
Device profile: FULL_PROFILE
Compilation started
1:2:9: fatal error: 'CL/cl.h' file not found
Compilation failed

Build failed!
Any help would be welcomed...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have not configured your visual studio for OpenCL.

Check whether INTELOCLSDKROOT is got added in environment variable if not add it or else
configure visual studio to find header file and openCL library files.

Configuring visual studio ->

```
    CL Header file 
    Properties -> All Configurations -> Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> SPECIFY_THE_PATH_OF_CL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY

    Linking CL Library 
    Properties -> All Configurations -> Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> Linker -> General -> Additional Dependencies ->SPECIFY_THE_PATH_OF_CL_LIBRARY_BASED_ON_64/32_BIT_MACHINE

    in linker -> input -> add OpenCL.lib
```

Comment: INTELOCLSDKROOT has been added in enviornment variable, and I have not configured visual studio....
but a window is provided by  the intel sdk in which i am getting this error.

Comment: it worked in visual studio....Thanks
But the error is occurring in intel kernel builder program that gets installed when we install intel sdk ... this pro is not finding the headers ... It will be of great help if you can help me on this..
But thanks again for getting me going

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the OpenCL runtime, and it is another file other than the SDK file

This is OpenCL runtime 64-bit [link](https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/IRC_NAS/17207/intel_sdk_for_opencl_applications_2020.3.494.zip)

Comment: I cannot find the file even after I installed the runtime, so I think this is not a solution

Comment: As of writing, this link is dead.

Comment: I've fixed it now to the latest one